# center text inside rotated div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a heading both vertically and horizontally inside a div that is rotated 45deg (`transform:rotate(45deg);`). 
Because the div is rotated - I rotate the heading the opposite direction (`transform:rotate(-45deg);`) and then apply regular centering techniques which doesn't work. What is the solution for this?

```css
#wrap {
 position: relative;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 top: 150px;
 background-color: blue; 
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap"><h1>some centered text</h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `h1` element you defined this style

```
h1 {
    ...
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

you're overriding the first `transform` property with the `rotate()` and doing so you're losing the centering effect obtained by the negative `translate()`: you should  chain instead the two transformation like so

```
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

You should also remove the default `margin` applied on the `h1` element (edit the demo and see what happens without `margin: 0;`)

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWjxeW?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

You should write one `transform` function right after another
I made a small change in your css, also added `text-align: center;`

```
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -100%);
```

```css
#wrap {
 position: relative;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 top: 150px;
 background-color: blue; 
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -100%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap"><h1>some centered text</h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);`

```css
#wrap {
 position: relative;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 top: 150px;
 background-color: blue; 
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap"><h1>some centered text</h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by encapsulating your `h1` in another `div`

```css
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: red;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  margin: 0; /* H1 has default margin, read more: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html *
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="text">
      <h1>some centered text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're happy to fix the height/width of your h1 elements, something like this will do it:

```
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
```

Comment: Would the person who commented me down care to at least say why?